# Get same instance viewModel from nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewmodel

I have a layout which is like that
MainActivity has a NavHost with 3 Fragments
SitesFragment, GroupsFragment, GalleryFragment

GalleryFragment has a ViewPager with 3 Fragments (Image, Audio, Video)

GalleryFragment has a GalleryViewModel

```
    private val galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel by viewModels()
```

So inside the ImageFragment i want to get the SAME INSTANCE of GalleryViewModel

```
    private val galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })
```

I tried to get it through the parentFragment but it is not the same instance!
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use activityViewModels() rather than viewModels() so your view models are provided by the activity hosting your fragments. https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment

Comment: No, i dont want the activity viewmodel. I want the GalleryViewModel

Comment: A view model has to be bound to a single lifecycle. In your case to be able to share a view model between fragments you should use your activity's lifecycle. If you access galleryViewModel as property from your fragment, it will probably cause unexpected results.

Comment: I guess i agree. However, isn t Fragment's lifecycle supposed to be bound to activity's lifecycle? And why the system decides to create a new instance and not give me the already existed

Comment: Internally, view models are provided by a viewModelStoreOwner. Both activity and fragment implement this interface. In your code when you use "by viewModels()", this do things internally. If you change this code to "by activityViewModels()", the view model will be provided by the activity's store so you get same view model from two different fragments. If you do what I said, you will see your problem is solved.

Comment: Its true, i had already done that! My question is how can we do that for sharing a Fragment viewModel.

Comment: For your question, it is possible that creating singleton view model and reaching it wherever you want. However, if you do that it is kept in memory indefinitely so it causes memory leaks or unexpected result. It is a bad practice from perspective of ViewModel because somehow view layer should have an ability to destroy the view model. Other solution is creating a ViewModel with a lifecycle and setting it into a app scope reference but it is also a bad practice.